# Python + lxml/xpath - проверить наличие элемента xpath и правильно создать условие

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Учу питон и в качестве практики решил запарсить сайт с расписанием сеансов кинотеатров.

В конце кода есть условие if (отмечено комментарием), которое на данный момент всем сеансам присваивает 3Д. Помогите пожалуйста решить 2 проблемы:

1) исправить код, чтоб он правильно проверял наличие `<span class="show-format">3D</span>` на странице http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F

2) чтоб 3Д присваивалось только тому сеансу, который реально идет в 3Д, а не всем в подряд сеансам.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def prepare(url):

    url = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(url.text)
    tree.make_links_absolute(url.url)
    return tree

def detailed_cinemas_films(url):

    showtimes_tab_url = '/showtimes/#!=&cinema-section=%2Fshowtimes%2F'
    tree = prepare(url + showtimes_tab_url)
    for film in tree.xpath('//div[@class="content"]'):
        film_name = film.xpath('.//a[@class="navi"]/text()')[0]
        for dates in film.xpath('.//li[contains(@class,"showtimes-day sdt")]'):
            film_dates = dates.xpath('.//div[@class="date"]/text()')[0]
            for times in dates.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li/a'):
                film_times = times.xpath('text()')[0]

                # Проблема: всем сеансам присваивает 3Д
                if dates.find('.//span[@class="show-format"]') is None:
                    pass
                else:
                    is3D = dates.xpath('.//span[@class="show-format"]/text()')

                print(film_name, film_dates, film_times, is3D)

detailed_cinemas_films('http://vkino.com.ua/cinema/kinoodessa-kinostancia')
```

Сейчас формат результата такой:

```
Терминатор: Генезис  5 июля, сегодня 21:00 ['3D', '3D', '3D', '3D']
Терминатор: Генезис  5 июля, сегодня 21:50 ['3D', '3D', '3D', '3D']
Терминатор: Генезис  6 июля, понедельник 10:10 ['3D', '3D', '3D', '3D', '3D', '3D']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
    for times in dates.xpath('.//ul[@class="showtimes-day-block"]/li'):
        film_times = times.xpath('a/text()')
        if len(film_times) == 0:  # Пропускаем уже прошедшие сеансы
            film_times = None
        is_3d = times.find('span')
        if film_times is not None:
            if is_3d is not None:
                print(film_dates, film_name, film_times[0], '3D')
            else:
                print(film_dates, film_name, film_times[0])
```